# What exactly is the Surface Brillouin zone?

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, weyl-semimetal

Everyone knows the Brillouin zone. But the term 'Surface Brillouin zone' seems ambiguous; it is used in many papers, including Wan et. al. (2011) in the classic paper first describing Weyl semimetals, but nowhere does it seem to be well-defined.

Does it just refer to the projection of the 3D Brillouin zone along an arbitrary axis (say $k_z$)? If so, when moving along the 'surface Brillouin zone', is $k_z$ fixed (at 0) or arbitrary?

Comment: Links to abstract pages?

Answer (score 1):

The surface BZ, by definition, is the Fourier transform of the surface unit cell. One way to calculate the surface BZ is by projecting all the Gamma points in the bulk BZ to the surface plane, and then finding the Wigner–Seitz cell of this lattice in the momentum space.

I have written a python program for drawing bulk and surface BZs for all different crystals.(https://github.com/Zijia-Cheng/DrawBZ/tree/main). Please check out if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

kz is not considered at all mathematically as long as we assume that kz=0 in the SBZ , physically it means that the contribution of the other set of wave vector which is the surface propagation wave vector or the parallel vector is limited with the perpendicular contribution that is assumed as well to be constant. so the SBZ is an assumption of neglecting the perpendicular contributors.